# for loop throwing and index.html:485 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to create a tooltip that uses a loop and if statement to add additional text if a condition is met. I'm doing this inside a leaflet onEachFeature function. When executing I'm getting an error like `index.html:485 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```
// add MCOSD w/ parking restrictions layer Open lands
var mcosdOpenPark = L.geoJson(bounds, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return feature;
  },

  filter: function (feature) {
    if (
      feature.properties.ClosStat ==
        "Open with parking and road restrictions" &&
      feature.properties.AGNCY_NAME == "Marin County Open Space District"
    ) {
      return feature;
    }
  },
  style: function (feature) {
    return {
      color: "false",
      fillColor: "#1a523d",
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
    };
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.on("mouseover", function () {
      layer.setStyle({
        fillColor: "#00ED3F",
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        color: "#00ED3F",
        opacity: 0.5,
        sticky: true,
      });
    });
    layer.on("mouseout", function () {
      layer.setStyle({
        fillColor: "#1a523d",
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        color: false,
        opacity: false,
      });
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < mcosdOpenPark.length; i++) {
      // declare variable for accessing object properties
      let props = mcosdOpenPark[i].properties;
    }

    //   create template literal for tooltip
    let popup = `<b>${feature.properties.SITE_NAME}</b><br>Closure Status: <b>${feature.properties.ClosStat}</b>`;

    if (mcosdOpenPark[i].properties.ResType) {
      console.log("I have restrictions, include in popup");

      popup += `<b>${feature.properties.SITE_NAME}</b><br>Closure Status: <b>${feature.properties.ClosStat}</b>'>${props.ResType}</a></p>`;
    } else {
      console.log("I have no url, exclude from popup");
    }

    layer.bindTooltip(popup);
  },
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) problem. You're referring to `mcosdOpenPark.lenght` in a scope where `macosdOpenPark` is undefined.

Comment: I'm confused - mcosdOpenPark is defined globally and inside the curly brackets for the L.geoJson. Does it need to be outside of onEachFeature method?

Comment: ...but it doesn't hold a value (other than `undefined`) after the constructor has done all the work, which includes calling `onEachFeature`. So in practice it's the same as referring to an instance in the constructor of said instance.